# How to tell SELinux to allow a python script to do "everything"

Tags: python, selinux

I'm new to SELinux and it is giving me a headache. I have a python service that runs a python script on my home directory (my_script.py). I've been running the service, seeing what aspect of it SELinux is blocking, and adding a new SElinux module

```
    allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'my_script.py' --raw | audit2allow -M my_script
# semodule -X 300 -i my_script.pp
```

However, each time I add a new module it keeps blocking another aspect of my script (reading files, writing files, then reading a socket etc.) I believe I have like 10 modules now, and I'm having trouble keeping track of all of them. I'm also worried that down the road my script might do something that SELinux doesn't like, but didn't come up during testing. Is there a way to tell SELinux, please let my_script.pp do whatever it wants (read, write, rename, etc.)? I am about to just disable SELinux, but really would rather not. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Since this question is fundamentally about configuring SELinux, it may be better suited for [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selinux).

Comment: For the general problem, if you configure selinux in "permissive" mode, then it will allow your script to operate but will still log all the AVC denials. Once you're done exercising your script you can create a module that includes all the necessary permissions. Whether this works for interpreted scripts or not (or if the rules would instead apply to the `python` binary) I'm not sure and would have to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

This need to do in below way:

1. Set SELinux is permissive mode
2. Run you script
3. Generate SELinux policy `ausearch -c 'my_script.py' --raw | audit2allow -M my_script`
4. Install it `semodule -X 300 -i my_script.pp`
5. Set SELinux in enforce mode again

Answer (score 0):

SE Linux is producing in its backend and it will help you recognise your issues more closely and give you methods of correction

If you are using Rocky Linux / Redhat use the below command to see SE Linux Messages and their remedy

sealert -l "*"